# DNF command to install all the rpms by specifying "*" in the command on centos 7.x

Tags: centos, kubernetes, rpm, dnf

I am using DNF package manager for installing rpms on centos 7.x.The rpms are checked out from the svn private repo. DNF is not able to install the rpm if I throw a command

```
dnf -y install docker-common-{{docker_version}}*.rpm
```

Whereas if I use rpm command to install the packages,its doing fine

```
rpm -i docker-common-{{docker_version}}*.rpm,its able to install
```

Is there any feature in dnf for installing the rpm without specifying whole line of rpm like below:

```
dnf -y install docker-client-1.12.6-61.git85d7426.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: `dnf` definitely support wildcards. What is the error you're getting?-

Comment: Are you running it from ansible or from the command line?

Comment: @msuchy from ansible

Comment: @Mureinik It's not able to install the rpm and its dependencies by using " * ". Every time it is hard to ansiblize the rpm name (if version change).

Comment: @Mureinik  dnf is supporting wildcards from console. But dnf is not supporting wildcards from ansible. Can any one help regarding this?

Comment: If you are using ansible you can try to use the raw builtin module (ansible.builtin.raw) instead de command one (ansible.builtin.command). You may also need to specify "/bin/bash" as executable in the args section.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply say the rpms are in your current directory with a ./* like:

```
dnf install ./docker-common-*
```

Comment: It's throwing " Error: no package matched".

Comment: you'll need to use the name of your packages in the directory you want to install. like if your rpm name is foo-bar-2.0.5.rpm then you need to use dnf install ./foo-bar-*  . Or alternatively you could do just: dnf install ./*.rpm